# Difference in parallel processing between java and python

Tags: java, python, parallel-processing, forkjoinpool

I make parallel processing program using java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool. While proceeding this program, I checked `top` and `htop`, and noticed that in `top` there are only one java process but in `htop` there are many processes.

My senior is writing parallel processing program using python, and he says that it is strange that there are only one process in `top`. And also he says that the "CPU usage" in `top` is usually over 90%. But my program uses only about 68%.

I thought that the cause is the difference in how to realize parallel processing between java and python. But I do not know whether it is correct. Please tell me the correct cause of this difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe it's just because you do not do the same things in your code. But we can't tell since we can't see it...

Comment: `top` does not show threads by default while `htop` does. You can use `top -H` and see what happens. It may be that the Python program uses processes rather than threads. I leave the difference between using threads to using processes to your research efforts.

Comment: I think we need to see your code.  There are lots of *incorrect* ways to write parallel code in Java that will result in no effective parallelism.

Comment: >Mr. vincrichaud and Mr. Stephen
Thanks for replying. I added source code link in my question.

Comment: >Mr. RealSkeptic 
Thanks for replying. I checked `top -H` and there are many **threads**. I'll research about parallel processing by using processes or threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did your senior implement multiprocessing or multithreading in python? To see the difference look at [Multiprocessing vs Threading Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python)

I'm pretty sure he is doing multiprocessing, which spawns multiple processes which are real copy instead of threads with shared memory. The behavior of `top`/`htop` is correct. `top` only shows the processes while `htop` also shows the threads.

The difference would be that you are using multithreading and your senior seems to use multiprocessing also explains the different CPU usage.

You can press `H` in `htop` which will toggle the view of the user threads. Now it should be nearly the same view as in top.